# Y axis scale with max set to 90 percentile of the data

Tags: vega-lite

I am using vegalite. I would like to configure the chart such that the Y max is set to the 90 percentile of the data and values above that would be clamped. This is so that spikes do not skew the vertical scale too much. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in the Vega-Lite grammar, as of version 4.1.

Domain extents can only be specified via fixed values, or dynamically via selections (See details in the docs [here](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#domain)). In particular, there is no way to dynamically compute domain extents based on data contents.

If you think such a feature should be added, you can file a Vega-Lite feature request [here](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/new?labels=Feature+Request+%3Araising_hand_woman%3A&template=Feature_request.md).